# Centralizar printf

Tags: c

Pessoal como faço para centralizar mensagens, textos simples?

```
printf("CLÍNICA DE ANÁLISES LABORATORIAIS\n\n");
printf("TRIAGEM ADMINISTRATIVA\n\n");
```

Essas duas linhas acima estão dentro da `main`.
Gostaria de centralizar elas em qualquer console.

Comment: Centralizar onde? Qual é o tamanho da linha? Isso pode mudar? É matemática pura.

Comment: Segue essa questão. Talvez ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461667/centering-strings-with-printf

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não existe um recurso no printf para centralizar a string, e o tratamento deve ser feito manualmente

Realizar o procedimento no printf:

```
printf("%", center_print("CLÍNICA DE ANÁLISES LABORATORIAIS\n\n",20));
printf("%", center_print("TRIAGEM ADMINISTRATIVA\n\n",20));
```

Segue a função para centralizar:

```
void center_print(const char *s, int width)
{
        int length = strlen(s);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<=(width-length)/2; i++) {
                fputs(" ", stdout);
        }
        fputs(s, stdout);
        i += length;
        for (; i<=width; i++) {
                fputs(" ", stdout);
        }
}
```

Conforme discutido com o autor da pergunta, a forma que mais lhe convém é a seguinte solução:

```
 printf("%*s", 40+strlen("CLÍNICA DE ANÁLISES LABORATORIAIS\n\n"));
 printf("%*s", 40+strlen("TRIAGEM ADMINISTRATIVA\n\n"));
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461667/centering-strings-with-printf

Comment: Esse `center` do `printf`é uma função?

Comment: Havia me equivocado ao montar a resposta, editei ela para que você pudesse entender.
Infelizmente não tenho como testar no momento, qualquer coisa é só avisar.

Comment: Então mais sem a função aí não funciona? ão entendi essa resposta sua aí.

Comment: Eu quero realizar o procedimento direto no `printf` e não criar função.

Comment: Sim só funciona com a função, para realizar direto no printf só se você fizesse algo desse tipo:

printf("%*s", 40+strlen("Texto"));

Comment: Até que funcionou, só que é o seguinte é conforme o formato da tela, tive que maximizar a tela para ver o resultado.

Comment: Tente diminuir o 40 e vê se ele não fica melhor, como eu disse, é um processo bem manual

Comment: Entendi, mas aí que tá se eu maximizar ele fica estático, não altera, entendeu? Acho que não tem como fazer isso.

Comment: Eu digitei isso que você sugeriu: `printf("%*s", 40+strlen("CLÍNICA DE ANÁLISES LABORATORIAIS\n\n"));` e sumiu, desapareceu a frase.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59984/discussion-between-jose-henrique-luckmann-and-andre).

Answer (score 0):

Seria necessário fazer uma função para gerar a string centralizada.

Eu fiz esta função `centerAlignText` usando a função `sprintf` para montar a string (tem alguns exemplos de como usar no `main`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *centerAlignText(char *field, unsigned int fieldWidth, const char *text){
    if (fieldWidth == 0 || field == NULL) return "";

    fieldWidth--;
    unsigned int len = strlen(text);
    unsigned int padding = fieldWidth > len ? (fieldWidth+1 - len)/2 : 0;
    sprintf(field, "%*s%.*s%*s", padding, "", fieldWidth-1, text, padding>0 && len%2!=fieldWidth%2 ? padding-1 : padding, "");

    return (const char *)field;
}

int main()
{
    char texto[] = "Ola Mundo!!";
    char campo[76];

    //Usa assim:
    centerAlignText(campo, sizeof campo, texto);
    printf("|_%s_|\n\n", campo);

    //Ou assim:
    printf("|_%s_|\n\n", centerAlignText(campo, sizeof campo, "Ola Mundo!"));

    //Com campo menor do que o texto a funcao corta o texto:
    char campo2[8];
    centerAlignText(campo2, sizeof campo2, texto);
    printf("|_%s_|\n", campo2);

    return 0;
}
```

Note que é necessário definir o campo onde o texto será centralizado criando um vetor de char com tamanho+1 para usar na função.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta usar um número específico de tabulações `\t`, geralmente organiza um pouco o resultado do código no console, não é bem uma questão de centralizar, mas apresenta resultados parecidos

```
printf("\t\tCLÍNICA DE ANÁLISES LABORATORIAIS\n\n");
printf("\t\tTRIAGEM ADMINISTRATIVA\n\n");
```

Comment: Oxi é uma tentativa de resposta oras...